# Convert "boolean bit array" to number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a "boolean bit array",

```
const array: boolean[] = [false, true, false, true]; // 0101
```

How can I get a number 5? Thanks

Comment: `parseInt(array.map(i => i+0).join(''), 2)`   //5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know TS, in pure JS it's

```js
a = [false, true, false, true]
b = a.reduce((res, x) => res << 1 | x)
alert(b)
```

To do the opposite (i.e. number to array):

```js
b = 5
a = b ? [] : [false]

while(b) {
  a.push((b & 1) === 1)
  b >>= 1
}

alert(a)
```

or

```js
b = 5

a = b.toString(2).split('').map(x => x === '1');

alert(a)
```

Comment: `res << 1 | x, 0`, what is this `, 0`? Because if I change to `res << 1 | x`, it still works. thanks

Comment: thanks again, how can I reserve the first `false` too? right now the result is `true,false,true`. How can I control the size of output array easily, like if I give a 4, it shows `false,true,false,true`; if I give a 5, it shows `false,false,true,false,true`

Comment: @HongboMiao: just add as many falses as you want: `while a.length < desired a.unshift(false)`.

Comment: I really do not understand what is happening in the reduce function `(res, x) => res << 1 | x`.  I know it is a bitwise OR operation.

Comment: @xinthose: it shifts the accumulator to the left by one and sets the rightmost bit to `x` (1 or 0). For example, let res=6 (110) and x = 1, then `res<<1` is 12 (1100) and `res<<1|x` is 13 (1101)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with typescript.

```
async maskBoolToInt(boolArray:boolean[]){
    let debugmode = true;
    if(debugmode){
        console.log('Debug : "maskBoolToInt"  Started');
        console.log('boolArray = ' + boolArray);
    }
    let bitArray:number[] = [];
    boolArray.forEach((element) => {
        bitArray.push(+element);    //convert bool to bit
    });
    if(debugmode){
        console.log('bitArray = ' + bitArray);
    }
    let result: any = bitArray.reduce((accumulator: number, currentValue: number) => accumulator << 1 | currentValue); //bitwise conversion to integer
    if(debugmode){
        console.log('result = ' + result);
        console.log('Debug : "maskBoolToInt"  Finished');
    }
    return result
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple number/radix with string split/join function to do that.

```js
const numberToBoolArr = (n: number): Array<boolean> => (n).toString(2).split('').map(r => r === '1')
const boolArrToNumber = (arr: Array<boolean>): number =>
    parseInt(arr.map(r => r ? '1' : '0').join(''), 2)
```

With the `boolArrToNumber`, you can verify that:

```js
console.log(boolArrToNumber([false, true, false, true])) // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the question, but touches on the related topic of representing an array of boolean values as a number and converting it back.

```
const boolsToNum = (bools: boolean[]) => { 
    return bools.reduceRight((res, bool) => res << 1 | +bool, 1)
}
const numToBools = (num: number) => {
    const bools = []
    while (num > 1) {
        bools.push((num & 1) === 1)
        num >>= 1
    }
    return bools
}
```

`reduceRight()` is used instead of `reduce()` to remove the need of reversing the array when converting a number back to bools. Its initial value used as 1 instead of 0 to preserve the size of array and to keep array starting `false` values. It works as if we passed in the array of +1 length, which first value is `true`. Costs 1 bit but removes the need of checking array length later. This bit is dropped when converting back by `while (num > 1)`

```
const array:Array<boolean> = [false, true, false, true]; // 0101

console.log(array, 'original')
const num = boolsToNum(array)

console.log(num, 'compressed')
console.log(numToBools(num), 'uncompressed')

// (4) [false, true, false, true] original
// 26 compressed
// (4) [false, true, false, true] uncompressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a naive solution

```
const booleanArrayToInt = (array: boolean[]) => {
  let res = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[array.length - i - 1]) {
      res += 2 ** i;
    }
  }
  return res;
};

console.log(booleanArrayToInt([false, true, false, true])); // 5
```